# Sign Extended Instruction for PIC24

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, instruction-set, pic24

How you can implement the Sign Extended Instruction in VHDL (in ALU) for PIC24?
I need to implement the following instructions and I don't have any idea how to implement SE.

```
LOOP: 
   mov 0x1020, w1 ; INW0=ff7f
   mov 0x1022, w2 ; INW1=8001
   ior w2, w2, w3 ; N=1
   se  w1, w1  ; N=0
REP1:
   bra n, REP1
   add w1, w1, w5
   se  w5, w6  , N=1
   bra n, CONT1
REP2:
   bra rep2
CONT1:
   mov w6, 0x1024
   bra LOOP
```

[This is SE in pic24's manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZyZv.jpg)

Comment: It would have been better had you added a description of the PIC24 `SE` instruction to your question to save me having to have looked it up. That would have made your question more complete.

Comment: I understand, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_instruction_listings) for the PIC24 shows that the `SE` instruction has this beahviour:

> `SE src,dst   C   Z   N   dst ← sign_extend(src), copy bit 7 to bits 15:8`

Copying bit 7 to bits 15:8 can be done using the *concatenation operator* (`&`), which joins together arrays to make bigger arrays:

```
dst <= src(7) & src(7) & src(7) & src(7) & src(7) & src(7) & src(7) & src(7) & src(7 downto 0);
```

This can be made more extensible by splitting this across two lines and using *part-selects* and an *aggregate*:

```
dst <= (others => src(7));
dst(7 downto 0) <= src(7 downto 0);
```

The first line fills up all the bits of `dst` with bit 7 of `src`; the second line overwrites bits 7:0 of `dst` with bits 7:0 of `src`.